# why does grep works when used as a variable and does not when used as a function in linux shell script?

Tags: linux, function, grep

I am trying to use grep as a variable and a function in a bash shell script. I get the desired output when grep is used as an variable. I do not get the desired output when grep is used as an function.

The script used for grep as a variable is as below:

```
#! /bin/bash

grep=$(grep -ico "mmshutdown: Finished" mmshutdown-output.txt)
#grep()
#{
#        grep -ico "mmshutdown: Finished" mmshutdown-output.txt
#}
status()
{
        echo $?
}

if [[ "grep" -gt "0" ]];
then
        echo
        echo "exit code of search  mmshutdown: Finished is $(status)"
        echo
        echo "FILE SYSTEM UNMOUNTED SUCESSFULLY"
        sleep 3
else
        echo "exit code of search mmshutdown: Finished is $(status)"
        echo "check output log file mmshutdown.txt"
        sleep 3
fi
```

the out put when we run the script is

```
[root@ad ~]# ./grep-variable.sh

exit code of search  mmshutdown: Finished is 0

FILE SYSTEM UNMOUNTED SUCESSFULLY
```

The script used for grep in function is as below:

```
#! /bin/bash

#grep=$(grep -ico "mmshutdown: Finished" mmshutdown-output.txt)
grep()
{
        grep -ico "mmshutdown: Finished" mmshutdown-output.txt
}
status()
{
        echo $?
}


if [[ "grep" -gt "0" ]];
then
        echo
        echo "exit code of search  mmshutdown: Finished is $(status)"
        echo
        echo "FILE SYSTEM UNMOUNTED SUCESSFULLY"
        sleep 3
else
        echo "exit code of search mmshutdown: Finished is $(status)"
        echo "check output log file mmshutdown.txt"
        sleep 3
fi
```

the out put when we run the script is

```
[root@ad ~]# ./grep-function.sh
exit code of search mmshutdown: Finished is 1
check output log file mmshutdown.txt
```

Could someone point out what has gone wrong here? Why is grep when used as function not providing desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your both programs are comparing "grep" with "0" not the output of the grep command.
Also -c option returns the number of lines matched.

Check the following code it works with grep as function. But as grep is as a function you will need to call original grep i.e. command with complete path else it will go in an infinite loop.
Send output to /dev/null and process on command execution status.

```
#! /bin/bash
set -x
#grep=$(grep -ico "mmshutdown: Finished" mmshutdown-output.txt)
grep()
{
        return $(/bin/grep -ico "mmshutdown: Finished" mmshutdown-output.txt > /dev/null)
}
status()
{
        echo $?
}


if  grep;
then
        echo
        echo "exit code of search  mmshutdown: Finished is $(status)"
        echo
        echo "FILE SYSTEM UNMOUNTED SUCESSFULLY"
        sleep 3
else
        echo "exit code of search mmshutdown: Finished is $(status)"
        echo "check output log file mmshutdown.txt"
        sleep 3
fi
```

Comment: my condition is that grep should provide a value greater than 0, only then it should execute the next command. Your command does not check for that condition. I am a newbei and correct me if i am wrong. Thanks for providing me a tip  on set -x in the script.

Comment: Please check I have made changes to send the output of /bin/grep to /dev/null. Now grep() method will return 0 on successful execution i.e. on matching "mmshutdown: Finished" and non zero value on any exception. If block will be executed if grep() returns 0 and else block on any non-zero value.

Comment: your concept also works in my case based on the output status. However can you describe why the grep when used as a function doesnt work and work when used as a variable. 'grep=$(grep -ico "mmshutdown: Finished" mmshutdown-output.txt)
grep()
{
        return $(/bin/grep -ico "mmshutdown: Finished" mmshutdown-output.txt)
}'

Comment: I have defined grep as a function only and it is working, right? Just noticed in your function grep you are not returning the result.

Comment: Your code is working and no issues in it. My requirement was if grep finds "mmshutdown: Finished" more than zero times, then the mmshutdown command should execute. Your concept is based on the output status of the grep command i.e if grep command finds "mmshutdown: Finished" regardless of the cout, the command is executed and it returns "0" status and thus the mmshutdown command is executed, which is also absolutely logical. My query was why did not grep as a function with my if condition [[ grep -gt "0" ]] did not work? Is there anything wrong that I am unable to identify?

Comment: 2 issues. 1 is you are not returning command output in grep(). 2 is you are comparing "grep" and "0", which compare grep with 0, not your output from grep().